# Qt: how to detect whether a widget is selected?

Tags: c++, qt, widget, focus, selection

I didn't see any signal/slot/function that could tell me whether a widget is selected by mouse?
Is it possible to have such an function to tell me whether the current QWidget is selected? And How could I differentiate between "the current widget is selected" and "one of its child widget is selected?"

Comment: Does general `QWidged` support selection?

Comment: By selected do you mean focused?

Comment: @Nejat, that is also Ok. What I want to achieve is when a Widget is clicked by mouse, it set certain value to 1, when the mouse click anything else, it set that value to 0.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can check focus on a widget using `hasFocus()` function. `focus` property holds whether the widget has keyboard input focus or not. You can also get the current widget of the application that has the focus using `QApplication::focusWidget()`. You can get a pointer to the focused widget like:

```
QWidget * fw = qApp->focusWidget();
```

When the focused widget is changed `QApplication::focusChanged(QWidget *old, QWidget *now)` signal is emitted.You can connect it to a slot in which you do what ever you like based on the focus change.

Comment: I used a qtimer to check the hasFocus()'s output of certain `customWidget` at 1Hz. No matter how I click that `customWidget`, the output is always false?

Comment: Do you mean it always returns false? What's the type of your widget?

Comment: Hi, I found that I need to setFocusPolicy before I could focus on this widget. But how could I clearFocus of the current widget when I click anywhere else(not on the widget)? Do I have to do it manually, or Qt have some flags for it?