# how to check that lineedit has focus?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a line-edit in which i want the 'bool' check for 'if-statement' as shown in codes below:
but what to type in "syntax for clicked" to verify that if the user is ready to input on that?

```
if self.lineEdit."syntax for clicked for edit"(True):
  {
   "any code hear"
  }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, do you want to know when the QLineEdit has the focus? Maybe you have a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: yes sir  i want the same

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28807064/qt-how-to-detect-whether-a-widget-is-selected, it may be what you're looking for

Comment: is there a way to check it directly on that conditional statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to detect when a widget like QLineEdit receives or loses focus then you must override the [`focusInEvent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#focusInEvent) and [`focusOutEvent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#focusOutEvent) methods, respectively.

In the following example I have created signals that are emitted in those events:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class LineEdit(QtWidgets.QLineEdit):
    focus_in_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    focus_out_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def focusInEvent(self, event):
        self.focus_in_signal.emit()
        super().focusInEvent(event)

    def focusOutEvent(self, event):
        super().focusOutEvent(event)
        self.focus_out_signal.emit()


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        le = LineEdit()
        le.focus_in_signal.connect(self.focus_in)
        le.focus_out_signal.connect(self.focus_out)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel("Label"))
        lay.addWidget(le)
        lay.addWidget(QtWidgets.QPushButton("Button"))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def focus_in(self):
        print("focus in")

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def focus_out(self):
        print("focus out")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = Widget()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Another method is to use the [`focusChanged()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#focusChanged) signal from QApplication:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        QtWidgets.QApplication.instance().focusChanged.connect(self.on_focusChanged)

        self.le = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel("Label"))
        lay.addWidget(self.le)
        lay.addWidget(QtWidgets.QPushButton("Button"))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot("QWidget*", "QWidget*")
    def on_focusChanged(self, old, now):
        if self.le == now:
            print("self.le received focus")
        elif self.le == old:
            print("self.le lost focus")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = Widget()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

If instead you want to verify synchronously if a widget has focus you can use the [`hasFocus()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#focus-prop) method.

Comment: thanks sir, could you help me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57878361/how-to-create-a-row-containing-different-lineedits-and-other-input-elements-on-a this question please?

Comment: Great response!  I have a question.  I'm interested in using the concept of the second example.  Why is the decorator included?  The code seems to run fine without the decorator.